# unstacking dataframe in R and Python

Tags: r, python-3.x

I'm working with panel data in python and I need to unstack my dataframe for testing purposes. In python everything works fine, however I'm trying to do the same in R and it seems like the unstack function works differently. Imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
data = np.array([['Id','AsofMonth','x1','x2','y'],
            ['A',1, 5, 6,10],
            ['A',2, 5, 4,12],
            ['A',3,6, 5,13],
            ['B',1,2, 6,2],
            ['B',2,2, 2,3],
            ['B',3,4, 4,5]],                
           )

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:])
```

I used the unstack function in python to unstack my dataframe:

```
df.sort_values(by='AsofMonth', inplace=True)
df1 = df.reset_index().set_index(['AsofMonth','index']).unstack(-1)
```

[image: outcome dataframe]

I tried to use the unstack en reshape function in R but I don't obtain the same answer as in python:

```
df <- data.frame(c('A','B','A', 'B','A','B'),
            c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
            c(5,2,5,2,6,4),
            c(6,4,5,6,2,4),
            c(10,2,12,3,13,5))

colnames(df) <- c('LoanID','AsofMonth','x1','x2','y')

df <- unstack(df)
```

What can I do to obtain the same results?

Comment: R's `data.frame` structure does not support MultiIndex on columns (or any kind of hierarchical indexing). Given that constraint, what is the use case for transforming your data into this shape? The `tbl_df` class from `tibble` / `dplyr` supports using columns similarly to row hierarchical indexes with its grouping system but there is no equivalent for column hierarchical indexes. You would have to define your own data structure to preserve  separate hierarchical indexes.

Comment: @bcarlsen - thanks for the explanation and I'd definitely take a closer at the tbl_df class. I want to unstack the data to incorporate a time series split. The time series cv assumes that a data frame is indexed by time. After the split, I can stack the data again for predicting purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce a closer result:

```
#Code
new <- reshape(df,timevar = 'LoanID',idvar = 'AsofMonth',direction = 'wide')
```

Output:

```
  AsofMonth x1.A x2.A y.A x1.B x2.B y.B
1         1    5    6  10    2    4   2
3         2    5    5  12    2    6   3
5         3    6    2  13    4    4   5
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. Indeed, it will produce similar results. Can I use the same function to stack it back?

Comment: thanks for sharing. Indeed, it will produce similar results. Can I use the same function to stack it back?

Comment: @Mike Yeah, just use `direction=long` that would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = LoanID, values_from = c(x1, x2, y))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  AsofMonth  x1_A  x1_B  x2_A  x2_B   y_A   y_B
#      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1         1     5     2     6     4    10     2
#2         2     5     2     5     6    12     3
#3         3     6     4     2     4    13     5
```